# How to deserialize a multi-shape JSON response with GSON and Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I have a restApi which its response can be something like this (if there is only one object to return):

```
{
    "keys":
    {
        "id":0,
        "name":"john",
        "pItems":12
    }
}
```

or like this if there is more:

```
{
    "keys":
    [
        {
            "id":0,
            "name":"john",
            "pItems":12
        },
        {
            "id":0,
            "name":"john",
            "pItems":12
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use a list for Model object, the first case doesn't work.
How can I deserialize it using Gson and Retrofit2?

Comment: Not a good design if an attribute with same name can be list or single object. You can write a custom deserializer which converts the single object of case to list.

Comment: @Smile I know its a really bad design but the restApi isn't mine! I just wanna use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you cannot change the design of the response, but are you sure you only can receive those responses? if is like this maybe you can create something like this:

```
class Response{
    public Object keys
}

class UserResponse{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int pItems; 
}
```

So you going to have two cases:

1. you can receive an UserResponse object
2. you can receive a List of UserResponse object

Then to validate if is a List of UserResponse, can be something like this:

```
if (keys instanceof List<?>){
    // then keys is a list 
}else{
    // then keys is a single object UserResponse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `keys` element is array or not and then deserialize accordingly.

Assuming, your Model class is UserWrapper.java

```java
import java.util.List;

public class UserWrapper {

    private List<User> keys;

    public List<User> getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }

    public void setKeys(List<User> keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

}
```

User.java is class corresponding to each element of `keys` attribute.

```java
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int pitems;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPitems() {
        return pitems;
    }

    public void setPitems(int pitems) {
        this.pitems = pitems;
    }

}
```

Code to deserialize based on type of `keys`

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonMain{

    private static String json = "YOUR JSON";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
        JsonElement keyselement = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("keys");
        UserWrapper userWrapper = new UserWrapper();
        if (keyselement.isJsonObject()) {
            userWrapper.setKeys(new ArrayList<User>());
            User user = gson.fromJson(keyselement, User.class);
            userWrapper.getKeys().add(user);
        } else if (keyselement.isJsonArray()) {
            List<User> users = gson.fromJson(keyselement, new TypeToken<List<User>>() {
            }.getType());
            userWrapper.setKeys(users);
        }
        userWrapper.getKeys().forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.getName()));

    }

}
```